# Set ActionBarDrawerToggle color

Tags: layout, drawer

In my app I'm using a Drawer Layout, following the example of [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

As you probably konw, the 3 lines of the Toggle button in the top-left corner are light grey... Well, I would like to set their color the white, because the ActionBar is in light blue.

Do you know how to do this? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it's really simple! I had to apply a white level in photoshop on res/drawable/ic_drawer.png, then reload eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `res/drawable/ic_drawer.png` image in you application folder.